# Linux script to search for string in a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am newbie to shell scripting. I have a requirement to read a file by line and match for specific string. If it matches, print x and if it doesn't match, print y.

Here is what I am trying. But,I am getting unexpected results. I am getting 700 lines of result where my `/tmp/l1.txt` has 10 lines only. Somewhere, I am going through the loop. I appreciate your help.

```
for line in `cat /tmp/l3.txt`
do
    if echo $line | grep "abc.log" ; then
        echo "X" >>/tmp/l4.txt
    else
        echo "Y" >>/tmp/l4.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: How many lines are in `abc.log`? 70?

Comment: I am searching for abc.log string in each line of file /tmp/l3.txt

Comment: I think I might see what is accounting for the line count -- how many times have you run this while testing? `>>` means append, so each time you run this, you are appending to `/tmp/14.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the urge to do looping ...

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /abc\.log/){print "x"}else{print "y"}}' /tmp/13.txt > /tmp/14.txt
```

EDIT after inquiry ...

Of course, your spec wasn't overly precise, and I'm jumping to conclusions regarding your lines format ... we basically take the whole line that matched abc.log, replace everything up to the directory abc and from /log to the end of line with nothing, which leaves us with clusterX/xyz.

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /abc\.log/){print gensub(/.+\/abc\/(.+)\/logs/, "\\1", 1)}else{print "y"}}' /tmp/13.txt > /tmp/14.txt
```

Comment: That looks simple..Sorry for not giving enough details..once I search for "abc.log" in each line,Whatever lines has this string will be in this format -Dabc.log=/abc/clusterX/xyz/logs..I need to print out clusterx/xyz to /tmp/l4.txt and whatever lines that dont have "abc.log",need to print a fixed string "Y" to /tmp/l4.txt corrspondingly..Results should retain original order..Really appreciate your help

Comment: any  thoughts? I would really appreciate

Comment: See my edit -  based on the extra input you gave it does what you asked (note: not necessarily what you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /tmp/l3.txt | while read line  # read the entire line into the variable "line"
do 
  if [ -n `echo "$line" | grep "abc.log"` ]  # If there is a value "-n"
  then
    echo "X" >> /tmp/l4.txt # Echo "X" or the value of the variable "line" into l4.txt
  else
    echo "Y" >> /tmp/l4.txt # If empty echo "Y" into l4.txt      
  fi
done
```

While read statement will read either the entire line if only one variable is given, in this case "line" or if you have a fixed amount of fields you can specify a variable for each field, I.E. "| while read field1 field2" etc...  The -n tests for if their is a value or not.  -z will test if it's empty.

Comment: Tried this..This is not giving expected results..If I have input file of 10 lines,I am getting 100 lines of result,where as I expect exactly 10 lines of result

Answer (score 0):

Why worry about `cat` and the rest before `grep`, you can simply test the return of `grep` and append all matching lines to /tmp/14.txt or append "Y":

```
[ -f "/tmpfile.tmp" ] && :> /tmpfile.tmp            # test for existing tmpfile & truncate
if grep "abc.log" /tmp/13.txt >>tmpfile.tmp ; then  # write all matching lines to tmpfile
    cat tmpfile.tmp /tmp/14.txt                     # if grep matched append to /tmp/14.txt
else
    echo "Y" >> /tmp/14.txt                         # write "Y" to /tmp/14.txt
fi
rm tmpfile.tmp                                      # cleanup
```

Note: if you don't want the result of the `grep` appended to /tmp/14.txt, then just replace `cat tmpfile.tmp /tmp/14.txt` with `echo "X" >> /tmp/14.txt` and you can remove the `1st` and `last` lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "awk" answer above is better. However, if you really need to interact using a bash loop, you can use:

```
    PATTERN="abc.log"
    OUTPUTFILE=/tmp/14.txt
    INPUTFILE=/tmp/13.txt
    while read line
    do 
            grep -q "$PATTERN" <<< "$line" > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo X || echo Y
    done < $INPUTFILE >> $OUTPUTFILE
```